# Non continuous function with directional derivatives zero in all directions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I was asked the following question:
A function f(x,y) has directional derivatives in all directions, and they are 0 in all directions. Does f have to be continous?

I thought I proved it by:

\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)-f(0,0)&=\lim_{r\to0}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)-f(0,0)\\&=\lim_{r\to0}r\cdot (f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)-f(0,0))/r\\&=\lim_{r\to0}r\cdot \lim_{r\to0}(f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)-f(0,0))/r\end{align}

The right limit is the directional derivative in direction $\theta$ which is said to be zero, and the left limit is zero and we get:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0)$$

Is there a mistake in this proof? Because the solution said that f does not have to be continuous.
Thank you!

Comment: What is $\theta$ in your calculation?

Comment: It is from polar coordinates and I chose the vector n = (cos(theta),sin(theta)) for the directional derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be continuous. Take, for instance$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }y=x^2\text{ and }x\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$It is discontinuous at $(0,0)$, but the directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ are all equal to $0$.

Comment: Thank you! do you know what is wrong in my "proof"?

Comment: What you did shows that, for *each* $\theta$, $\lim_{r\to0}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=f(0,0)$. The function from my answer also has this property. But continuity is more than that. It consists of proving that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$(\forall\theta\in\Bbb R)(\forall r\in[0,\delta)):|f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=f(0,0)|<\varepsilon.$$That is, $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ must be close to $f(0,0)$ when $r$ is small enough and for *every* $\theta$.